# ¿Como obtener registros de usuarios que el total de transacciones sea igual o mayor a 100.000?

Tags: javascript, php, mvc

Tengo una tabla donde se registran los id (en número) de usuarios y valores (en número) que corresponden a dinero de una transacción. Cada registro es una transacción.

Quiero hacer una consulta en la que la suma del dinero de las transacciones sea mayor o igual a 100.000 por usuario, pero que traiga los registros de forma individual.

Estoy intentando algo así

```
"SELECT * FROM $tabla
WHERE $tabla.usuario_tv IN
    (SELECT usuario_tv, SUM(monto_tv) AS total
    FROM $tabla t1
    WHERE t1.usuario_tv = $tabla.usuario_tv
    HAVING total >= 87000)"
```

¿Alguna idea de como puedo hacer la consulta??

Comment: ¿Y esa consulta que otorga, funciona parcialmente, da error?

Comment: Esa consulta es simplificable

Comment: primero agrupas por usuario y luego filtras por el total gnerado de la agrupacion